# Google Maps (Marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{"stylers": [{"saturation": -100},{"gamma": 0.8}, {"lightness": 4},{"visibility": "on"}]},{"featureType": "landscape.natural","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"},{"color": "#5dff00"},{"gamma": 4.97},{"lightness": -5},{"saturation": 100}]}]     
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contactusmap'), myOptions);
var markerNew = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  'images/googlepin.png',
  new google.maps.Size(32,37)
);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906),
  map: map,
  icon: markerNew,
  title:"You found us! :)"
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
```

The marker doesn't seem to appear but no errors.. any ideas about what I should do for it to appear? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906),
  map: map,
  icon: markerNew,
  title:"You found us! :)"
});
```

Here in the above code,

Missing to instantiate the `google.maps.LatLng`

```
 position:   google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906), 
           |
           |_____ Add the new Keyword
```

Fix it as

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906),
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/yV6xv/3966/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code its working fine if you comment

```
styles: [{"stylers": [{"saturation": -100},{"gamma": 0.8}, {"lightness": 4},{"visibility": "on"}]},{"featureType": "landscape.natural","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"},{"color": "#5dff00"},{"gamma": 4.97},{"lightness": -5},{"saturation": 100}]}]
```

and also add "new" keyword in

```
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.900169, 14.511906),
```

please check this ..hope will works for you....

Comment: **Nope, it will work with styles.** The actual problem is OP is missing the instantiate the `google.maps.LatLng`.. You can check the fiddle in my answer.